# How to use/call methods of Redis search with ioredis npm package

Tags: node.js, redis, full-text-search, ioredis

i am trying to implement redis search in my node js project.completed all the configuration on redis server(using cloud).now in the project we use **ioredis** npm package.searched a lot but unable to find how to call redis search methods like create,search using this package.
so please help me out with this.
just for testing i have use another package "redis" and i can call all the method of search easily.for example : await client.ft.DROPINDEX('idx:animals')
but i want to use ioredis package. how to do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ioredis [`redis.call()`](https://luin.github.io/ioredis/classes/Redis.html#call) can execute arbitrary command in Redis, so you can wrap any RediSearch command in it.

```
redis.call('FT.DROPINDEX', 'idx:animals')
```